# GET vs. POST when the request is some arbitrary size

Tags: api, rest, http, post, get

I understand the semantics of GETting vs. POSTing, one endpoint should get data, the other should post it. The latter being a request that you may not wish the user to be able to easily replay.

That said, on the project I'm working on at the moment - the approach has been to POST to endpoints that are clearly responsible for responding with data, and these endpoints do not transform data in any way.

The reasoning behind this has been that **the payloads are (potentially) of considerable size and *seem* more appropriate for a body as opposed to a query string**.

Can anybody please shed light on which request would be right for a GET request that takes a large request payload? I'm not asking for opinion, I'm asking for what would be compliant to RESTful deisgn.

### Further Context

The request is potentially large due to the fact it's a search DTO from the UI, where users may choose to pass any number of filters or search terms.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody please shed light on which request would be right for a GET request that takes a large request payload? I'm not asking for opinion, I'm asking for what would be compliant to RESTful deisgn.

Today's answer: [It's OK to use POST.](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

For requests that are [fundamentally read-only](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.2.1), we'd *like* to use standardized HTTP semantics to communicate that to general purpose components, so that they can themselves do intelligent things.

BUT: [GET](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.1), while being both [safe](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.2.1) and ubiquitous, isn't an appropriate choice when you need to include a message-body in the request:

> content received in a GET request has no generally defined semantics

So if you can't, for whatever reason, copy the information you need into a resource identifier, then GET is not an option.

Now, if your payloads are consistent with WebDAV, then you might be able to use one of the safe methods described in those specifications.  But, as far as I can tell, they aren't really appropriate for general use.

---

Tomorrow's answer: the HTTP-WG accepted a proposal for a [safe-method-with-body](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body-03).   So we should eventually expect to see a [registered HTTP method](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) that is safe and has defined semantic for the request content.

Then, depending on what those semantics are, we may be able to use it for requests like yours.